# Firefox checked radio button error message

Tags: firefox, radio-button, checked

I have the following html:

```
 <input type="radio" name="Ctrl_DondeCobrar" id="Ctrl_DondeCobrar1" value="    <%=TrdsINC.getTraduce(CodigoFormularioINC,TipoFormularioINC3,TTidioma,"lit004")%>"/>
 <label class="literalRegistro">          <%=TrdsINC.getTraduce(CodigoFormularioINC,TipoFormularioINC3,TTidioma,"lit004")%       >:</label>

<input type="radio" name="Ctrl_DondeCobrar" id="Ctrl_DondeCobrar2" value="<%=TrdsINC.getTraduce(CodigoFormularioINC,TipoFormularioINC3,TTidioma,"lit012")%>"/>
<label class="literalRegistro">    <%=TrdsINC.getTraduce(CodigoFormularioINC,TipoFormularioINC3,TTidioma,"lit012")%>:</label>
```

In a javascript I use

```
if (Ctrl_DondeCobrar[0].checked)
```

This code in Internet Explorer works but in Firefox I get the message

```
 ReferenceError: Ctrl_DondeCobrar is not defined
```

Could someone help me to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Carlota Vina

Comment: Can you put your js code?

Comment: I would like to know how to get the radiobutton selected in FireFox and because this sentence works in Internet Explorer